# What is the meaning of this X[0, :] notation?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

While doing a course, I came after a code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from testCases_v2 import *
import sklearn
import sklearn.datasets
import sklearn.linear_model
from planar_utils import plot_decision_boundary, sigmoid, load_planar_dataset, load_extra_datasets

%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(1) 
X, Y = load_planar_dataset()

plt.scatter(**X[0, :], X[1, :]**, c=Y, s=40, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral);
```

What is the meaning of this `[n,:]` type of notation in arrays?

Comment: What did you look up for answering this question?

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means in your matrix X, take at row n, take all the columns (: is shorthand for all).
For higher dimensional arrays, it would mean for the first dimension at n, take all of the second dimension (:) and all of the other dimensions (implicitly, all non-listed dimensions are taken as :).
In practice, it is no different from x[0], in your case.